# Beanstalk Java platform with parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the **Java platform** in a Beanstalk application and I'm trying to read an environment property and pass as a java system parameter:

My Procfile inside the zip bundle says:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar app.jar
```

The defined "Environment Properties"

```
JAVAOPTS -> -DXyz=123
```

But during launch, I see in the logs:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS
```

Is it possible to pass variables to the java process in such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the Procfile wont't allow parameters to be passed that way. My work around war, calling a shell script that passes the parameters:

Procfile

```
web: sh ./run.sh
```

./run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar application.jar $JAVA_ARGS
```

That allow parameters to be se in the Environment Variables of beanstalk configuration console.